# Passing secret as an Chef attribute while using encrypted databags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have already created a databag item which is existing on the chef server.
Now, I am trying to retrieve value of that databag item in Chef recipe
For that purpose, I am creating Chef Databag and trying to pass the secret as an attribute:

```
secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("#{node['secret']}")
masterkey = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("databag_secrets", "databag_masterkey", secret)
```

I have declared node['secret'] as follows in the attribute section:

```
default['secret']="lTW4d+2Wfjlf1gZ42x3qsJh4/GcwqTc5+kS62qKeAHrhzTiL/Bxp+hq3itwudNfUFggCOEaMTsR+Q/qgjx6unKNvKWMKIdCeNM8I4jCUeT2VDaU6C1VxIMrVqfpUmInLuHOaUpVdlnlejkeLBL2KzH5vA8Xx5t2eACBRvrHacTwORMgVr/pnSKBcSzC/wXGoc7bGk7kTd6SaswRfZHnOowxfs2xkGJOFbzyTLZNAqkrJJurBq/ycYGRK2J3ycNyTwISfVgG9YAvP6prHKPsWTp3JgOWNIeZ9ZMSKUy8Lh0vopluXJhSd1WC6ltNcHxSb"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: FFI_Yajl::ParseError: lexical error: invalid character inside string.
          S62qKeAHrhzTiL/Bxp+hq3itwudNfU
                                        FggCOEaMTsR+Q/qgjx6
                     (right here) ------^
```

Please let me know if it is allowed to pass secret as an attribute in Chef. If yes, how should I do that?
If not, what is the best way to pass secret in a secure way?

Comment: Try with single quotes, instead of double quotes...

Comment: This literally defeats the point of encrypted data bags. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef%2FEncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret), `#load_secret` should be passed a path to a file containing the secret. If you don't want to put the secret in a file (this is the preferred way), you can pass the secret to every `#load` call (as [shown here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef%2FEncryptedDataBagItem.load)):

```
Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load(data_bag, name, secret = nil)
```